# Apply style to column in a table?

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors

Is it possible to apply a style to a column? for example lets say I want the 2nd column to be red (in reality it'd be more complicated). Below/[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EEJfc/1/) I gave the 2nd column the class b but I have no idea how to make the 2nd column of every row red. I only know how to style the header

```
.b { color: red; }

<table>
    <th>a</th>
    <th class="b">b</th>
    <th>a</th>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/EEJfc/3/

Use nth-child selector.

In your case

```
table td:nth-child(2) { color: red }
```

Comment: I think you need to update the JSFiddle link :P still showing the old example, but your solution is correct ;) +1

Comment: Oh, yeah, always forgetting about this. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Use `nth-child`

```
tbody tr td:nth-child(2){color: red;}
```

[**Demo JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EEJfc/2/)

Comment: *upvote*. Sorry I tend to accept answers from people who have the lowest score.